# Truncated Backpropagation for Many-to-One RNN

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have been looking at this article on RNNs:

https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/hello-world-rnn-83cd7105b767

But, my interest is in a many-to-one RNN. So I am confused in how to apply truncated back propagation.

Also, I'm interested in using varying time-steps in my training and testing - if possible. Is it possible to achieve this?

To summarize the question:
 1. How to use proper truncated BP for many-to-one RNNs?
 2. How to train/test using varying-length sequences?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post by Danijar that implements the many to one rnn in tensorflow. https://danijar.com/introduction-to-recurrent-networks-in-tensorflow/ Regarding the dynamic time steps, the `dynamic_rnn()` allows you to specify any number of time steps.

```
# Batch size x time steps x features.
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, 28])
```

by passing data into the `dynamic_rnn()`, this will create an rnn or a GRU or LSTM and will be unrolled `time_steps` automatically based on the second dimension in `data`.